# CSS transform skew, how to make image top horizontal?

Tags: css, image, transform, skew

The question is: how to make .box2 image top horizontal, like the first .box div ?

See the FidDle: http://jsfiddle.net/PArPj/2/

```
.box2{
    height:600px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -ms-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* Opera */
    transform:skewY(-20deg);
    float: left;
}

.box2 img {
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    -ms-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:skewY(-20deg); /* Opera */
    transform:skewY(-20deg);

    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* Firefox */
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* Opera */
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform:rotate(35deg) skewY(-20deg);`

Comment: Where it use on .box2 or .box2 img ?

Comment: Just on `.box2` - it will just rotate the div to counteract the skew.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't what you want, but it makes the top line on your image horizontal.